# Backend script?

Tags: php, web-services, backend

I'm not even sure how to approach this one.

How would you have a backend script on a site that runs 24/7 and say sends an email every minute. Is something like this possible to write in php. For example I don't want the actual page to be open in the browser the server (Godaddy in my case) would automatically do it.

I dont need a physical script. Just a technology that would allow me to do so!!!!!

Comment: You should check to see if your godaddy account is even able to handle cron jobs. In many cases it will require shell access.

Comment: `I dont need a script.` Is that a question?

Comment: @Tom - You sure? Do yo mean you already have your script written but you just need a way to call it every minute? Or do you mean you know of some other way to have a cron job send emails?

Comment: A script to send spam email? :)

Comment: What exactly is a "physical script"? Like a printout?

Comment: Your two options are: 1) A scheduled script which executes once a minute and exits after each run (cron job) 2) a long-running script that sleeps for a minute, does something, then sleeps again. (daemon)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look up `php-cli` and `crontab`.

Comment: Good answer! My post exactly lol. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use cron and call for a script url using i.e. wget or curl or code a php-cli app. PHP-Cli is fun!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. 
You need to write a script for sending email messages and create a cronjob and make sure if it's possible to set up execution interval to one minute (somewhere minimal repeat time is 15mins)

Data should be read from database in a loop (e-mail addresses for instance) and then you can use mail() function to send some messages.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a crontab like so

```
$>crontab -e
*/1 * * * * php -r /path/to/script.php
```

That will execute your script every minute.
Godaddy most likely has an option on their web interface to setup crontabs or cronjobs to make it easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use crontab to send email evry minute

Use this:

```
crontab -e
*/1 * * * * php -r /path/to/phpscript.php
```